# PHP - Many variables or One array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a question, what is more faster ...

1. I make many variables that contain all of my data, *or*
2. I make one array in one variable that contain all of my data and access it

Comment: What kind of data do you have?

Comment: You use array mainly when you need to reference elements dynamically via a key, so they are of *different usage*.

Comment: It really is best not to be worrying about this level of optimisation with php imo. When dealing in scripting languages you should be looking more at what helps you get the job done in a readable and sensible manner. Arrays are designed for containing a large number of items of similar data and are easier to move from function to function. With regards to access speed I would say individual variables are faster but they will make your code much more difficult to work with, especially if the data needs to be kept as a group.

Comment: This may depend on how you access the array. Integer index is faster than hash map.

Comment: Why this nonsense question is not closed and deleted?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just a try :)

### Test 1

With 5 variables

```
$myvar1 = 'hello';
$myvar2 = 'hello';
$myvar3 = 'hello';
$myvar4 = 'hello';
$myvar4 = 'hello';

print_r(memory_get_usage());
```

Resut : 618600

### Test 2

with 5 array keys

```
$myvar = array();
$myvar['var1'] = 'hello';
$myvar['var2'] = 'hello';
$myvar['var3'] = 'hello';
$myvar['var4'] = 'hello';
$myvar['var5'] = 'hello';

print_r(memory_get_usage());
```

Resut : 620256

Comment: You only describe that it uses more memory. Not that they are faster. +1 for the memory overview ;).

Comment: I just want to point out that 0.2% difference in memory consumption doesn't show any difference. You need to look at CPU usage instead of memory consumption. You also need to benchmark passing those values and more.

Comment: I [confirmed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14338038/956397) those results with 10000 variables.

Comment: @Laurence
Its late, but i just reached here now, i have to create 1500 variables or array of same size, but this answer proves that array will consume more memory, how much depends on key structure (int or String), so individual variable refer fast.

Answer (score 22):

Short: **Accessing a variable is faster.**

But still you might use arrays because of better [code quality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14338033/956397). To get better performance use caching. Anyway you should handle performance problems *only* when they occur!

#### Array Test

```
$n = 1000000;
$startTime = microtime(true);  
for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++)
{
    $x = $a[1];
}
$endTime = microtime(true);  
$elapsed = $endTime - $startTime;
echo "Array: $elapsed seconds";
```

#### Variable Test

```
$startTime = microtime(true);  

for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++)
{
    $x = $v;
}
$endTime = microtime(true);  
$elapsed = $endTime - $startTime;
echo "Variable : $elapsed seconds";
```

#### Results

Array: 0.092 seconds

Variable : 0.064 seconds

Also node that using arrays with string as index will be much slower (hashmap). Compare [zend_hash_find](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_hash.c#zend_hash_find) vs [zend_hash_index_find](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_hash.c#zend_hash_index_find).

How big the array is does not really make a difference if I use `$a = array_fill( 0, 1000, 1 );` and `$x = $a2[999];`

#### Memory

Not ask but also interesting is the memory usage. So I created an array with 10000 elements and 10000 variables.

```
$a = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10000; $i++)
{
    // one array
    eval('$a[] = "test";'); // 3454128
    // Variables
    //eval('$a' . $i. ' = "test";'); // 3552360
}
print_r(memory_get_usage());
```

Array: 3454128

Variables: 3552360

So arrays do use slightly less memory.

Comment: Even if an array is slower. It doesn't mean that they are always faster. What will happen if you send 100 items in an array to a function or 100 variables?

Comment: @Laurence `What will happen if you send to function 100 variables?` Someone will be fired? :) But if seriously - that is a good question, even if it should not rise at all as making such functions is terrible (I found a function with more than 50 arguments in one of my projects - that is crazy! doing modifications there scare me to the death)

Comment: @FAngel you should make a new question for that ;)

Answer (score 4):

People here say that arrays are faster. But arrays are also variables. if you use an array - you still need to access it like any variable and additionally you need to access an item in array. So, it looks to me that array used like a storage for variables is not the best idea.

Additionally - arrays are used to store some array data. Like category id => category name pairs, for instance.

```
$catId1 = "Category 1";
$catId2 = "Category 2";
$catId3 = "Category 3";
```

Code like above would be... strange. You are loosing many features of an array, for instance, can't go through all categories in `for` loop. So, for array data - array is what you need.

Once you have different kinds of data (talking about meaning of that data, not its type like integer or string) you should better use variables:

```
$requested_category = 1;
$requested_category_name = "Some category";
$category_processing_result = "Ok";
```

instead of array:

```
$varsArray['requested_category'] = 1;
$varsArray['requested_category_name'] = "Some category";
$varsArray['category_processing_result'] = "Ok";
```

With variables any IDE will help you to write those names, such code is easier to read and support. And that is more important, as for me.

Even if they are slower somehow, or take more memory - that is not a worst problem in terms of speed/memory usage for sure.

Comment: Code quality is indeed worth more.

Answer (score 3):

Many variables are faster than an array mainly because an array is an ordered map (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and therefore by definition for each and every value in the array, a reference key to the value in the array is also assigned.
This costs extra memory and can have significant impact when speaking of hundreds of thousands of records in an array.
The performance decreases as the number of records increases.
This overhead can be avoided by using scalar variables instead of arrays.

Recently I was working on a profiler to measure memory and execution time using a tick callback.
At first I used an array to log events and to keep track of all the measurements at each tick interval.
After putting these values in separate scalar variables instead of in the array, I discovered that performance increased significantly (between 10 - 20% with 100000 - 1000000 records respectively).

However, when an array only has a few records, the difference with scalar variables is nihil and performance should not really be an issue.
In such cases arrays might suit the situation better and be more effective, improve readability, maintenance and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Storing all your data in one array could be faster, depending on how you're handling your data. I would recommend grouping each group of data that has a close relation to eachother in an array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

make all relative data in a array, arrays are faster.

Comment: They also though that the earth was flat. Can you add prove?

Comment: @DinoBabu That just helps to say what approach takes more memory. But tells nothing about speed. Not that I'm saying I know that arrays are slower than variables, but as for me - they should not be faster and I would like to know if I'm wrong or not.